# "Порталы держат на фронтонах..."?

Tags: выбор-слов

> Порталы этих павильонов держат на фронтонах стрелки солнечных часов и
>   указания на астрологические знаки и астрономические явления.

Если я "указания" заменю на "указатели", я заметно изменю авторский замысел?

---

---

Дополнение от автора:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Крытые галереи расходятся от жилого центра виллы и заканчиваются
>   флигелями. Под фронтонами порталов этих павильонов тени гномонов
>   неслышно скользят по полям солнечных часов, давая указания на время,
>   астрологические знаки и астрономические явления. Сад предлагает
>   завораживающие перспективы. В том числе несколько обзорных точек на
>   одну из знаменитых ротонд мира – редкую по типологии круглую
>   христианскую церковь.

Comment: Надо бы объект видеть. Может там таблички с рисунками или письменами, а может стрелки-указатели.

Comment: Меня больше волнуют порталы, которые что-то там держат на фронтонах, - это грамотно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно бы, конечно, видеть эти фронтоны павильонов. Если портал - это вход, ворота, а их фронтоны (верхушка с двускатной крышей) треугольной или овальной формы, всё нормально, на  стене фронтона вполне могут быть солнечные часы. Можно сказать, на стене фронтона находятся часы, а можно сказать "порталы держат" - как бы олицетворение. Не знаю, о чём речь, но иногда солнечные часы в виде какой-то конструкции находятся и на самом верху, на коньке фронтона, тогда точно держат. Здесь речь только о стрелках, видимо, на стене только стрелки, цифры и знаки. Думаю, "указатели" точнее "указаний", если таковые указатели (в виде стрелок?) имеются. А вдруг нет? Вдруг просто цифры обрамлены этими знаками? Надо бы знать, как это выглядит, о чём идёт речь.

Comment: В вопрос добавлено фото (порталов/фронтонов) автора и правленный им текст.

Comment: Тогда всё верно, но можно заменить "давая указания" на "указывая.". А порталы держат на фронтонах - нормально.

Answer (score 2):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно, стрелок нет и не было никогда.

Фронтон, если уж по терминологии для начинающих, это ниша, чаще треугольной формы, образованная карнизом и двускатной кровлей портика (где портик — выступающая в плане часть входной группы фасада).

*На фронтонах порталов этих павильонов тени изящных гномонов неслышно скользят по периметру часов с зодиакальными знаками.* (Смысл такой, но форму надо рихтовать, конечно.)

Правка после правки.

*Под фронтонами павильонов — смотрящие на солнце монументальные часы, тенями от гномонов, неспешно скользящих по циферблатам, синхронно отсчитывают уходящее время (и указывают на астрологическими знаки).*

Скобки по той причине, что неясно и не видно: что за знаки? что за явления, и как на них можно указывать?

Comment: В вопрос добавлено фото (порталов/фронтонов) автора и правленный им текст.